# Linux and HADOOP are installed on one drive of a machine, can I have HDFS on another drive of the computer

Tags: linux, hadoop, hdfs

I am a starter in learning HADOOP. I was having a windows laptop with the hard drive split into 4 drives. I have recently emptied a drive (D drive) and installed Ubuntu 14.04 on it and installed HADOOP and HIVE. Now, while trying to work on HADOOP through linux, I am facing space constraints.

LINUX is installed on D drive and Windows was there in C drive. When I want to move data in the local file system to HIVE, I have to copy it into HDFS first and then to HIVE, now my question is can the other two drives on my computer be of any use in this regard either serving as local file system or as HDFS, most importantly as HDFS. If yes, please tell me how to do that. Any help is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**AUTOMOUNT WINDOWS DRIVE AT STARTUP:**

In order to use your windows drive as a ubuntu drive within ubuntu, you have to auto-mount the drive at startup.

1. In terminal, create a mount point in **/media** folder using:

   `sudo mkdir /media/win-d`
2. Find your windows drive path or UUID using:

   `sudo blkid`

> **/dev/sda2**: LABEL="win-os" UUID="**18E0B145E0B1991A**" TYPE="ntfs"

3. Edit **/etc/fstab** using `sudo nano /etc/fstab` in terminal to add the below line (to automount windows drive at ubuntu startup)
   Use either one:

`/dev/sda2              /media/win-d        ntfs  defaults             0  0`

(or)

`UUID=18E0B145E0B1991A  /media/win-d        ntfs  defaults             0  0`

> **NOTE: Restart your system if necessary.**

Now, you can use this mounted drive for HDFS storage or local filesystem.

**HDFS DIRECTORIES:**

Based on your hadoop version, change the hdfs directories using `file://` in **hdfs-site.xml** (on all nodes) if you want to use local filesystem instead of HDFS filesystem.

Comment: It mounted well but after restarting, an error message appeared and the partitions disappeared all together from Devices list in Ubuntu. The error message was "Auto mount has errors, click 'S' to ignore and continue or 'D' to configure manually". Please help me out with this..